# Change the HTTP request before sending

Tags: http, facebook, http-proxy

I want to change an HTTP request before sending the data.

I tried WebScarab for the purpose, but it looks like it doesn't work with Facebook properly. (And I dealing with Facebook (https if possible, otherwise http) here)

Is there any good way to change the HTTP request before sending it?

Note: Normally this would be an application that sends data to a locally running proxy server on some other port before sending the data to the server.

Extra: My aim is to edit the name to which the Facebook comments are tagged to. But that's not really important unless you know a way to do the same in a different way.

Comment: maybe Fiddler http proxy might but I don't know how to use it..

Answer (score 1):

Try **[burp proxy](http://portswigger.net/burp/proxy.html)**.

Answer (score 1):

Like a comment said, I'd go with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). Its a good debugging proxy, and allows changes to the stream. It has a lot of plugins, and lets you write your own (if you know .NET).

Comment: I did not mention: I am running Fedora at home. Mac otherwise. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Charles web Proxy it has a rewrite tool for modifying HTTP requests.